# How to make biblatex behave like apacite?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, apa-style

The title is probably too broad. The problem I face is that I am working on a beamer presentation, and because beamer conflicts with apacite, it has been suggested that biblatex be used instead. I have tried it but there are a few issues.

1) Full list of authors the first time, but uses "et al." in all subsequent cites, e.g. first time: (Doe, Smith, & Johnson, 2009); 2nd time and on: (Doe et al., 2009)

2) No comma between the authors and the year. How do I make it output something like (Smith and Johnson, 2009) instead of (Smith and Johnson 2009)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love `biblatex`. That said, in the following MWE `beamer` and `apacite` go together well.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some citations}
\cite{A01}

\cite{A01}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: The same example with `biblatex` (using the style `apa`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some citations}
\parencite{A01}

\parencite{A01}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's weird that I searched for "apa" in the biblatex.pdf (version 1.5a) and it didn't tell me that they have an "apa" style. Btw, I have a follow-up question. How do we make it do "Author, Buthor, & Cuthor (2001)"?

Comment: The `apa` style is not provided by standard `biblatex`, but by the package `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make the APA style do something other than it does or that the APA style has a problem?

Comment: I get error: `! Package biblatex Error: Option 'sorting=apa' invalid.`
when trying 2nd example.

Comment: On BibLaTeX 3.4, I get the error `! Package biblatex Error: Option 'date=apalong' invalid.` when trying 2nd example. Did anything change about apa style support?

Comment: Nevermind, updating to the latest version of biblatex solved the issue. Will leave comments in case someone else gets similarly stuck.