# Beamer + apacite: Citation undefined

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, apacite

I am doing a presentation with the `beamer` class using the `metropolis` theme. Currently I am using RStudio and compile the file with XeLaTeX. Texmaker is an alternative.

[How to make biblatex behave like apacite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23651/how-to-make-biblatex-behave-like-apacite/23654#23654) - did not work for me. May be I need to compile with more than just 1x XeLaTeX?

I would prefer to use Bibtex with apacite being able to just include a .bib file for `\bibliography`. However, I read that there exist some conflicts?

Errors:
- Rerun to get \PageLabels entry
- Citation `...` undefined

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

% various symbols
\usepackage{gensymb}

% bibliographystyle
\usepackage{apacite}

% Bilbliography
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{Ref1,
  author = {{Test author}},
  title  = {Test title},
  year   = {2016},
  url    = {http://testurl.com=},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usetheme[sectionpage = progressbar, numbering = fraction]{metropolis} 

% title preface
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Frame1}
    \cite{Ref1}
\end{frame}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}%in case more than 1 slide needed
{\footnotesize
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Try with the second example from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23651/how-to-make-biblatex-behave-like-apacite/23654#23654. It works fine with metropolis theme, if compiled with `xelatex, biber, xelatex, xelatex`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I now use Texmaker with a custom "quick build" command compiling `xelatex, biber, xelatex, xelatex` -> `xelatex % | biber % | xelatex % | xelatex %` referring to this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/104937. RStudio seems to be to to basic for this approach atm. Add it as an answer and I´ll accept it!